# Strange behaviour with mapping drive / Windows2008 / CIFS

Tags: windows, share, cifs

I've a strange situation here...

Context : 
NAS Filesystem under Unix 
A farm of 15 compute unit 
The farm work all the time and process stream buffer from one nas path to an other one.

A mapping drive is connected on all my Compute Unit with the cifs protocol.

What's happened :

I lose my connection on client side (windows 2k8R2) randomly, and  :

- net use => nothing. No active connection.
- netstat => the socket on port 445 is always established.

Then :

- if I try to re-mount the mapping drive => Failed...
- If I try to access the share with UNC path => Failed...

After the crash, windows try to connect (UNC or Mapping drive) on port 80 in place of 445.
When I restart the machine, I recover my share.

So my question is : 
What going on ? 
Why on a failure Windows don't release the network connection on port 445 ?

Any ideas ?